# Where should project documentation be stored in a typical maven project

Tags: maven, documentation

Where should should project documentation (requirements, etc.) be stored in a typical maven project.

None of the directories listed in [Introduction to the Standard Directory Layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) page is an obvious candidate.

Comment: I would vote for '/docs'. Everything under '/src' is maven world, better not to mess with that. I also think that project itself is not good for saving documentation. Consider installing wiki.

Comment: In maven all source files go under /src.  Documents that you edit are source files, they should go under /src somewhere.  If you start adding new top level directories willy nilly, then your project is not following maven conventions and will be difficult for others to comprehend.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no convention. If you want the documentation to be part of the generated site, obviously `/src/site` is a good place. Maybe you can even write the documentation in the [APT](http://maven.apache.org/doxia/references/apt-format.html) format?

But more likely you have a set of `doc`, `pdf` and `xls` files, graphics, e-mails, etc. You can either place them under `/src/site` as well and put hyperlinks in the site or... define your own convention, sadly. Typically I have seen `/src/main/doc(s)`, `/src/doc(s)` or even `/doc(s)`.

You don't want to place your documentation in `/src/main/resources` or `src/main/webapp`, as the files will then be part of built artifact (JAR/WAR) which is rarely desired.

Comment: Is't src rather for source?

Comment: If your doc format is processed into other formats, it is the source for documentation, so placing it under src would make sense (/src/main/doc for documentation of the code, /src/doc for documentation of the project). If the documentation files are to be  used "as is", then a /doc in parallel to /src seems more logical.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/site-generation-sect-dir-struct.html
recommends the following structure

```
sample-project
+- src/
[..]
+- resources/
|  +- images/
|  |  +- banner-left.png
|  |  +- banner-right.png
|  |
|  +- architecture.html
|  +- jira-roadmap-export-2007-03-26.html
[..]
```

Comment: Sorry @RobE, my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [maven-javadoc-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/javadoc-resources.html):

> The `<javadocDirectory/>` parameter can be used to include additional resources, like HTML or images, in the generated javadoc. You can then link to these resources in your javadoc comments. By default, all javadoc resources are in `${basedir}/src/main/javadoc` directory. Note that you need to set the `docfilessubdirs` parameter to copy these.

Comment: Do you see the difference between documentation in general and JavaDoc? :)

Comment: Somewhat. If you view JavaDoc as a format/documentation generator, the problem is never documenting just the APIs, but writing the docs around them which explain their use. Having that *in* the JavaDocs/Code, and linking to the APIs, always seems to be a good idea.

If you are documenting something *other* than the APIs, I would think something else could be used (e.g. markdown).